# not able to get background changed, it worked before?

Tags: html, css

I had a different background color on this page before then it went away for some reason, I tried fooling around, simplifying code and still it will not work, this is what I have now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Stock Ninja Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css" media="all">
</head>
<body>
<h1><center> Trade</center> </h1><h2><center>Ninja</center></h2>
<p><center><label><input type=text placeholder="            USERNAME" maxlength="20"></label></center></p>
<p><center><label><input type=text placeholder="            PASSWORD"maxlength="20"></label></center></p>
<p><center><label><input type=text placeholder="        USER KEYWORD"maxlength="20"></label> </center></p>
<p>
<center><select name="crust" multiple onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
  <option value="Program.html" selected>Program</option>
  <option value="Account.html">Account</option>
  <option value="Support.html">Support</option>
  <option value="Education.html">Education</option>
</center>
</select>
</p>
<p><center><button>Submit</button></center></p>
</body> 
</html>
```

Here is the CSS, its very simple!

```
html, body{background-color:#e3dac9;}
```

Comment: your code should work, can you post home.css too?

Comment: Which browser/version? Should work.

Comment: I did post Home.css thats what Im not understanding. Im using Chrome Version 37.0.2062.103 m

Comment: I just updated the browser, loaded each page file into their own folders, triple checked the file names and associations the program and nothing, I'll revisit, thanks for all the input!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me here.  Check that your CSS file is in the correct location and that it's being linked to properly. Or include it in the html file.

```
<style>
    body{
        background-color:#e3dac9;
    }
</style>
```

it sounds like the CSS file isn't being used.  Either it isn't there or your path is wrong.  Try an absolute path when linking to your css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/css/styles.css"  type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: That is my only CSS actually, Im just working in baby steps. I changed the name of the CSS file from styles to Home.css and changed it also in the HTML.

Comment: It works inside the HTML, however I wanted an external CSS file, not a work around. Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 html{background-color:#e3dac9 !important;}
```

As you can see I don't use body selector because the html selector has a higher priority and I 
have added "!important" to override any possible default backgrounds.Vote up if it worked :)

Comment: So it is indeed a bug in your browser I can't give any other sollution I am sorry!!!

Comment: Recommending `!important` is very bad practice in a case like this. It's simply not necessary.